# How to force diagonal of a distance matrix to zero with RcppArmadillo?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have the following Rcpp/RcppArmadillo function which computes correlation distances in a matrix

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat cordiss(NumericMatrix X){  
   int nX = X.nrow(), kX = X.ncol();
   arma::mat XX(X.begin(), nX, kX, false); 
   arma::mat output = (1 - arma::cor(XX.t(), XX.t()))/2;   
   return output.t();   
}
```

After sourcing it with Rcpp::sourceCpp, I can do something like:

```
d <- cordiss(matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=10))
```

However, I get non-zero values in the diagonal (because I guess of machine precision ?), while I really need these numbers to be set to zero for further processing of the distance matrix. Is this a problem of matrix *type*?. How can I fix this, without having to set the diagonal 'manually' to zero afterwards (in Armadillo or R), eg:

```r
diag(d) <- 0
```

Indeed I want to use a similar function to compute distance between two different matrices for which I cannot predict where the columns of the matrices will be equal
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to guarantee zeros, as any implementation of an algorithm using non-integer numbers is in effect using [*approximations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) of such numbers.

Your best bet is to manually set the diagonal to zero, which you can do in Armadillo via [.diag()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#diag). For example, `output.diag().zeros()`

Comment: ok, thanks this seems pretty easy, but what if I have now a function accepting two input matrices for which I want to compute distances, and with one of the columns of the two matrices being exactly the same? The near-zero value won't be on the diagonal. Is replacing these values the only solution?